# XML parsing in C#

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-serialization

How can I Parse this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RESULT imgURL="www.diedomain.de/images/request_12345.jpg">
<ITEM name="test AG" status="nicht betroffen" />
<ITEM name="test3 GmbH" status="betroffen" />
<ITEM name="versuchs GmbH" status="nicht betroffen" />
<ITEM name="bergwerk GmbH" status="betroffen" />
</RESULT>
```

in C# easiest? I want to get all items in an List and imgurl too? Can you show me an method for this one? i tried serializer, but did not work.

This also did not work:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><RESULT imgURL=\"www.diedomain.de/images/request_12345.jpg\"><ITEM name=\"test AG\" status=\"nicht betroffen\" /><ITEM name=\"test3 GmbH\" status=\"betroffen\" /><ITEM name=\"versuchs GmbH\" status=\"nicht betroffen\" /><ITEM name=\"bergwerk GmbH\" status=\"betroffen\" /></RESULT>");
List<XElement> items = doc.Descendants("ITEM");
string imgurl = doc.Element("RESULT").Attribute("imgURL").Value;
```

Comment: Also, don't post comments as answers. Post them as comments.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to replace `myXml` with a valid URI reference to the XML that you want to parse.

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(myXml);
List<XElement> items = doc.Descendants("ITEM");
string imgurl = doc.Element("RESULT").Attribute("imgURL").Value;
```

Comment: XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><RESULT imgURL=\"www.diedomain.de/images/request_12345.jpg\"><ITEM name=\"test AG\" status=\"nicht betroffen\" /><ITEM name=\"test3 GmbH\" status=\"betroffen\" /><ITEM name=\"versuchs GmbH\" status=\"nicht betroffen\" /><ITEM name=\"bergwerk GmbH\" status=\"betroffen\" /></RESULT>");
          
            List<XElement> items = doc.Descendants("ITEM");
            string imgurl = doc.Element("RESULT").Attribute("imgURL").Value;

Answer (score 0):

IMHO [LINGQ to SXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is the best choise. Tehere are a lot of examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vbasic/bb688088)

Answer (score 0):

Look at using linq to xml - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using plain old `XmlSerializer` on an annotated class that you write, RESULT. RESULT would have an imgURL `string` attribute and a `List<>` of ITEMs.

Comment: how can i do it with serialiser?

Comment: Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx . You'll have to make a class called RESULT. Inside of it, make a public property whose type is string, name is imgURL, and has the `[XmlAttribute]` attribute on it, and have a second public property for the list of ITEMs, etc.

Comment: Don't even use XDocument. Use a stream and give it to XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the option of running XSD.exe (from the VS command line) to get it to generate a CLR class with the apropriate attributes to serialise to/from the XML format you give (with the XmlSerializer class).

You can also do this by hand, but XSD will do the hard work for you.